# How can I check an data layer variable array in Tag Manager to use as a pageview trigger condition?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager

In my code every time a page loads, it grabs the departments that page is related to from the WordPress taxonomy and builds an array that is sent to a datalayer variable in tag manager. for example:

in PHP

```php
$department = ["accounting", "sales", "support"];
```

and in JS

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
    'department': '<?php echo $department; ?>'
});
```

in GTM, I want to create a pageview trigger called sales_pageview which fires a tag every time a page loads where "department" contains "sales" and I am not sure how to parse that array in GTM to look for that array element.

Any suggestions anyone? I added some screenshots for reference:

[image: tag config]
[image: trigger config]
[image: variable config]
[image: datalayer push code]
[image: GTM Assistant Output 1]
[image: GTM Assistant Output 2]
[image: GTM Assistant Output 3]
[image: GTM Assistant Output 4]
[image: Dev Console Messages]

Comment: Is this the actual code? This will give you 'department': 'Array'. You should try "echo json_encode($department);" or "echo implode(',', $department)". Both will give you a string which you can use "contain" on. If you want an array use json_encode and leave out the single quotes before and after.

Comment: Actually I had changed it to:
department': '<?php echo json_encode($department) ?>';
which created the JS object. So- if I simply reference my custom variable in GTM and use 'contain' in the trigger it will check the array to match an array element?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `contain` in your trigger

Here is the demo example.

I push a datalayer with array

[image]

And I set up a trigger use the `datalayer variable` to contain `test456`

[image]

[image]

Then it will fire as expected.

---

Thanks for the a lot of screenshots. They are helping!

The problem becomes very clear now

Your datalayer is pushing a json-encoding object

[image]

So the value is

```
'["public-works", "human-resource"]'
```

But your trigger is

[image]

```
equals human-resource
```

Finally

```
'["public-works", "human-resource"]'

is not equal to

human-resource
```

So the tag not fired.

Here is the suggestion:

1. Check the datlayer value is matching your expecting or not. If not then change it.
2. Is the trigger can change to `contains` ? Or it is not the business rule you want.

Comment: This is crazy. I hard coded the value as 'department': 'human-resources'. In preview mode I see the value in the datalayer area. If I console log the datalayer var, I see department with the correct value, I have the department variable defined but when I tell the trigger to fire on SOME pageviews if department contains human-resources it still says not fired. Arrrgh. Not really sure why it isn't firing at this point. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @simlpymarkb Can you add some screenshots about the datalayer and how you wrote it. Also the preview about not triggering the tag status

Comment: I added some screenshots. Maybe I am going crazy but this looks like I didn't miss a step.  Any ideas?

Comment: I originally had it at "contains" but it still doesn't fire. Out of curiosity I switched it BACK to contains and it's not firing.

Comment: Is it possible that the datalayer value isn't even making it into GTM?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with the trigger. After investigating I noticed the value was set to null.

I changed the trigger from pageview to DOM ready and it fired. I guess this was a case where the answer was fairly simple and easy to overlook because I was so focused on the DLV itself.